# C++ Boolean Values Different than 0 or 1

Tags: c++

I am doing a simple code using PCL and OSG libraries, but I am getting a strange behaviour on booleans of my objects.

Here is my Class Definition:

```
class BulletCallback : public osg::NodeCallback
{
public:

        bool found_cube;
    BulletCallback() {
                found_cube = false;
        }

    virtual void operator()(osg::Node* node, osg::NodeVisitor* nv);

};


class BulletTransfAndCallBack 
{
    public:

        int start;
        BulletCallback* updateCallBack_btc;
        osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> bulletTransf;

        BulletTransfAndCallBack(BulletCallback* callback, osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> transf ){
            updateCallBack_btc = callback;
            bulletTransf = transf;

            time_t currentTime;
            time(&currentTime);
            start = currentTime;
        }
};

std::list< BulletTransfAndCallBack* > BulletTransfAndCallBackList;


int main(int argsc, char** argsv){

std::list< BulletTransfAndCallBack* >::iterator i = BulletTransfAndCallBackList.begin();

                while (i != BulletTransfAndCallBackList.end())
                {


                        bool removed = false;



                        bool found_c = (*i)->updateCallBack_btc->found_cube;
   //this variable "found_c" has values like 123, 265... and so on, values larger than 1, I don't understand, it was supposed to be 1 or 0

                        cout<<"Found_Cube? ["<<distance(BulletTransfAndCallBackList.begin(), i)<<"] "<<found_c<<endl;
                        if(found_c == true ){
                                time_t currentTime;                     
                                time(&currentTime);

                                int msec = currentTime - ((*i)->start);


                                if(msec > 10){



                                    camera2->removeChild((*i)->bulletTransf);
                                    i = BulletTransfAndCallBackList.erase(i);
                                    removed = true;
                                }


                            }
                        if(removed == false){
                                ++i;
                        }
                }

}
```

The variable "found_c" used inside my Main method has values like 123, 265... and so on, values larger than 1, I don't understand, it was supposed to be 1 or 0.

But inside the method "operator" of the class BulletCallback I only see values of 1 or 0.

Can someone help me? What is this?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: The values start changing when I add a new BulletTransfAndCallback to the list, but I use a new BulletCallback... here is the code:

```
        mtx.lock();

        BulletCallback* bulletCB = new BulletCallback();
        BulletTransfAndCallBack* btc = new BulletTransfAndCallBack(bulletCB, bulletTransf );
        BulletTransfAndCallBackList.push_back( btc );
        static_cast<osg::Node*>(bulletTransf)->setUpdateCallback( bulletCB );

        mtx.unlock();
```

EDIT2: So I have showed the both class definitions, the Main method.. and snippet of the code when I add a new bullet and attach the UpdateCallback...

So the other piece of code that was lefting was this one:

The void method "operator" of the BulletCallback, here it is:

```
void BulletCallback::operator()(osg::Node* node, osg::NodeVisitor* nv)
{

        osg::PositionAttitudeTransform* bulletTransf = static_cast<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform*>(node);

        bool btc_found = false;

        BulletCallback* updateCallBack_btc_this;
        BulletTransfAndCallBack* btc; 

        mtx.lock();
        std::list< BulletTransfAndCallBack* >::const_iterator iterator;
            for (iterator = BulletTransfAndCallBackList.begin(); iterator != BulletTransfAndCallBackList.end() && btc_found == false; ++iterator) {

                    if((*iterator)->bulletTransf == bulletTransf ){
                        btc_found = true;
                        updateCallBack_btc_this = (*iterator)->updateCallBack_btc;
                        btc = (*iterator);
                    }
            }
        mtx.unlock();



        mtx2.lock();
        osg::Vec3 v = bulletTransf->getPosition();

    pcl::PointXYZRGBA ballNeighborPoint;

        //verificar se bateu em algum cubo virtual
        if(updateCallBack_btc_this->found_cube == false){

            osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> cubeTransf;
            osg::Vec3 cubePos;
            std::list< osg::ref_ptr<osg::PositionAttitudeTransform> >::const_iterator iterator;
            for (iterator = cubesList.begin(); iterator != cubesList.end() && updateCallBack_btc_this->found_cube == false; ++iterator) {
                    cubePos = (*iterator)->getPosition();
                    if(abs(v.x()-cubePos.x()) < 5 && abs(v.y()-cubePos.y()) < 5 && abs(v.z()-cubePos.z()) < 5){
                        updateCallBack_btc_this->found_cube = true;                 
                        camera2->removeChild( (*iterator) );
                        cubeTransf = (*iterator);
                        cout << "Cubo destruído! Boa!" << endl;
                    }
            }

            if(cubeTransf != NULL)
                cubesList.remove(cubeTransf);

            if(updateCallBack_btc_this->found_cube == true)
                checkWinning(); 


        }


    std::vector<int> search_indexes;
    std::vector<float> search_radiuses;

    ballNeighborPoint.x = -v.x()/100.f;
    ballNeighborPoint.z = - (v.y()-20)/100.0f;
    ballNeighborPoint.y = -v.z()/100.0f;

    kdtree->radiusSearch (ballNeighborPoint, 0.05, search_indexes, search_radiuses);

    if (search_indexes.size() == 0 && updateCallBack_btc_this->found_cube == false){
            v.y() -= 1;
          bulletTransf->setPosition(v);
    }else{

                ballNeighborPoint.x = -v.x()/100.f;
                ballNeighborPoint.z = -v.y()/100.0f;
                ballNeighborPoint.y = -v.z()/100.0f;


                kdtree->radiusSearch (ballNeighborPoint, 0.05, search_indexes, search_radiuses);

                if (search_indexes.size() == 0){
                    v.z() -= 1;
                      bulletTransf->setPosition(v);
                }else{
                        node->removeUpdateCallback(updateCallBack_btc_this); 
                        //BulletTransfAndCallBackList.remove(btc);
                        //camera2->removeChild(node);
                }

        }

        if(v.y() < -300){
            node->removeUpdateCallback(updateCallBack_btc_this); 
            //BulletTransfAndCallBackList.remove(btc);
            //camera2->removeChild(node);
        }
        mtx2.unlock();
        //cout << "T: " << BulletTransfAndCallBackList.size() << endl;
        cout << "CCC: " << updateCallBack_btc_this->found_cube << endl;

}
```

I don't have more code involving this boolean variable..

Comment: You must have undefined behaviour somewhere. Try to reduce the code to a smaller, self-contained sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I added the code corresponding to the UpdateCallback method, the method "operator" of the class BulletCallback... I dont have any more code messing with the boolean variable..

Comment: *I don't have more code involving this boolean variable.* It won't be in the code that sets the boolean. It will be in the code that does a memory copy over memory that it should not be writing to. Why can't you show an SSCCE?

Comment: Way too much code. You're supposed to *reduce it* to a *smaller* self-contained example. Your sample neither self-contained nor small.

Comment: I can't reproduce a simple code for you to test it, because you would need alot of libraries.. :/

Comment: That word simple, I do not think it means what you think it means, @DarkLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

The problem was that this call:

```
node->removeUpdateCallback(updateCallBack_btc_this);
```

It removes the updateCallBack from being called on the scene, and besides that it cleans the memory used by updateCallBack_btc_this, and my boolean variable was inside that.

This method is cleaning the object automatically, C++ shouldn't do this.. that why many guys take hours to find the bug. Like me.. When there is no BUG, it was just a method that cleaned the memory used by the object -.-